# Why is the inconsistency with Close Month?

Tags: reporting, date

I have created a report that gives the closed opptys of previous years.

When trying to understand, I get a wrong: Summarize by Close Month option, as it shows the last month of 2012 as the close month.

[image]

the total number reported, is actually smaller than the one I get, If I report on opptys from the same period: (Previous Fiscal Period)

Fiscal year settings:
[image]

- Why does the Summarize shows 2012 opptys?

---

I took a sample opty. In the oppty page, the close date is: 01/01/2013

[image]

In the report it shows: 31/12/2012

[image]

---

To make it even wierder (can it?) - the process I do is: export the opptys (and relevant data out to a new report).
In that report, the same oppty has a close date of: 1/1/2013

[image]

After the Dataloader -> Insert - the same three rows have different close date

[image]

-- I thought it to be a Time zone issue, as the opptys were from Bangladesh, but apparently, I have the same behavior on 2 opptys form the US.

The forecast in our org (for now) is not visible to any user - hidden in the only oppty layout we have) - so I don't think it's that.

---

Only 1 close date in the filter drop down

[image]

Comment: "All detailed boogins"? Any chances it's a custom report type and some of fields you dropped or are filtering on aren't in fact from Opportunity? Do you use custom fiscal years by any chance?

Comment: Don't you use Boogins in your org?  ^^ J/K it's a custom object, just typo in the plural name. thanks for that. Fiscal Year is regular (see image) - Is that the thing? closing month?

Comment: Weird. If you'll view some of Opportunities from this group of December'12, what close dates do you see? Could it be that these opps had forecasted revenue for example? I have "ending month" in my org as well so I don't think it's that... If the "Close Date" in the timeframe filter is definitely coming from the right object then I'm really puzzled what's going on.

Comment: I still suspect a timezone issue. It wouldn't matter where the opportunity is created, it would depend on your time zone offset.

Comment: @DanielHoechst Yes, but that would not explain the last edit I inserted. check the 3 lines in the excel, and in the reported object.

Comment: What is your time zone offset?

Comment: Default is +2 GMT. I have the same for a Bangladesh and New York opptys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussing with Salesforce support, and thinking this might be a bug - as we say in software industry: it's a feature.

The result is posted here: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=When-I-import-using-the-Data-Loader-why-are-my-date-values-changed-1327108298219&language=en_US

- The easy solution I took was to update the Date field on my CSV file, into the SF native format:

  =TEXT(A2,"yyyy")&"-"&TEXT(A2,"mm")&"-"&TEXT(A2,"dd")&"T12:00:00.000Z"

Once completed the update, the insert was working as intended.

Comment: Aren't timezones fun?

Comment: It still doesn't explain how (according to your screenshots) Opps with blank Close Date were put into the group where Close Month is in 2012. Crazy.